# Finding the most common ocurrences of 5 different numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to tweak a code to not only find the most occurrence of a number but for 5 different numbers in a worksheet. The code that I have now works for one number and every time I try a next statement it errors out. I am working in Excel 2010

```
Sub FindOccurance()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Set dic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
xMax = 0
xOutValue = ""
For Each Rng In WorkRng
    xValue = Rng.Value
    If xValue Then
        dic(xValue) = dic(xValue) + 1
        xCount = dic(xValue)
        If xCount > xMax Then
            xMax = xCount
            xOutValue = xValue
        End If
    End If
Next
MsgBox "The most common value is: " & xOutValue & " Appeared " & xMax & "    Times"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, how is the data organised in the spreadsheet? Could it be anywhere? Is it restricted to a certain column/row?

Comment: It appears that the code is not checking the dictionary to see if the key (the recurring value) is present. If it is then add its value plus one to count. If the key is not present you need to add another key.

Comment: You could also use the countifs function to come up with the same information. Just a thought.

Comment: The information is all in concurrent columns example would be B:F, and it will be updated monthly. Eventually I will have buttons set up on a different sheet in the workbook to call up the code and then put the values into cells on that particular sheet.

Comment: @Fred Wilson, I will try the countifs and see if I can get it to work that way also. Thx for the input.